# Unable to launch webkit or take a screenshot with playwright

Tags: automation, playwright, playwright-python

But it works with chromium.

playwright: 1.8.0
node: 14.15
Ubuntu: 20.04

this is my code.

```
const playwright = require("playwright");

(async () => {
  for (const browserType of ["chromium", "firefox", "webkit"]) {
    const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto("http://whatsmyuseragent.org/");
    await page.screenshot({ path: `example-${browserType}.png` });
    await browser.close();
  }
})();
```

Comment: What does it do? What are some error messages?

Answer (score 1):

On ubuntu 20.04, I was getting errors when running my first playwright script:
`node first_script.js` after installing via `npm i -D playwright` (playwright v1.10.0 and v10.19.0) per [playwright install instructions](https://playwright.dev/docs/intro/)

```
    const { webkit } = require('playwright');

    (async () => {
      const browser = await webkit.launch();
      const page = await browser.newPage();
      await page.goto('http://whatsmyuseragent.org/');
      await page.screenshot({ path: `whatsmyuseragent.png` });
      await browser.close();
    })();
```

saw errors that included:

- "error while loading shared libraries: libharfbuzz-icu.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"

Per several bugs [#1935](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/1935) [#2621](https://github.com/microsoft/playwright/issues/2621), running the following allowed me to run successfully:

`sudo apt-get install libgles2 gstreamer1.0-libav libharfbuzz-icu0 libwoff1 libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0  libgstreamer-gl1.0-0 libwebp-dev`

then tried to run 2nd script with chrome(chromium), firefox and webkit on same ubuntu 20.04 `node second_script.js`

```
const playwright = require('playwright');

(async () => {
  for (const browserType of ['chromium', 'firefox', 'webkit']) {
    const browser = await playwright[browserType].launch();
    const context = await browser.newContext();
    const page = await context.newPage();
    await page.goto('http://whatsmyuseragent.org/');
    await page.screenshot({ path: `example-${browserType}.png` });
    await browser.close();
  }
})();
```

and got errors:

- [pid=532053][err] XPCOMGlueLoad error for file /home/playwright/.cache/ms-playwright/firefox-1238/firefox/libxul.so:
  [pid=532053][err] libdbus-glib-1.so.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
  [pid=532053][err] Couldn't load XPCOM.

installed firefox and 2nd script ran successfully:

```
sudo apt-get install firefox
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it I was missing this library libgstreamer-plugins-bad1.0-0:amd64